# Can we use "these days" with the present perfect?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, tenses

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

"I've been really busy these days"

OR

"I'm really busy these days"

I may be wrong but for some reason it feels funny to use "these days" with the present perfect tense since, to me, "I've been really busy" implies that "I'm not that busy anymore", which is in contrast with what the phrase "these days" implies (= "I'm still busy"). Am I wrong?

P.S. I have asked this question to some native speakers of English and I got some contradictory answers. Could it be a regional thing?

Comment: "I have been really busy these last few days" works, but I'd consider "I have been really busy these days" unacceptable.

Comment: I would hesitate to call it ungrammatical, but it is certainly infelicitous.  One might hear it spoken, but I wouldn't want to see it in writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/day?q=day) this expression is used to speak about the present, that is, an ongoing present, taken to begin a little before true present and considered to continue similarly in the future.

- (informal) used to talk about the present, especially when you are comparing it with the past
  *These days kids grow up so quickly.*

Answer (score 2):

The term *these days* is informal enough that its meaning can be stretched slightly to mean *recently* as well as the dictionary definitions of *now* or *at present*. Obviously

> I've been really busy now

would be incorrect, but

> I've been really busy recently

is fine. Pedants may insist on the dictionary definitions, which would constrain it use, but

> I've been really busy these days

seems to be acceptable to me. One can easily infer the intended meaning from the tense of the verb.

Comment: "I'm really busy these days" is my choice, and I find "I've been really busy these days" jarring. I haven't consulted a dictionary (and I'm pretty sure looking for 'have been really busy these days' would be fruitless) so I'll keep my opinions to 'comments'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Each to his own, and I always value your input. My opinion is that we shouldn't rush to ascribe precise meanings to informal phrases. If we use *these days* to mean *recently* often enough, it will appear in the dictionaries eventually. There are worse abuses of our language, innit?

Comment: Worse things than giving opinions / preferences as _answers_? You mean no pickled red cabbage with the meat and potato pie tonight?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My opinions are all I have to offer.

Comment: You're barred from research?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, but facts bore me. Actually, I found a good answer that would support your position, but if I can find it, so can you.

Answer (score 1):

"**These days**" is an adverbial phrase and equivalent to "**lately/recently**". If you can say "lately/recently", you can say "these days".

Comment: I'd accept 'Dejected, he sat by the roadside' but not 'sad, he sat by the roadside'. I'm happy neither  with 'I've been really busy these days', nor with your use of logic (with hidden and unproven assumptions).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm afraid that *'Sad, he sat by the roadside'*. is perfectly grammatical. If you refer to Thought Co https://www.thoughtco.com/free-modifier-grammar-1690807 you will be rewarded with the information you need. There are no hidden and unproven assumptions - this is basic ELL grammar. >Adverbial genitive - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive

Comment: I'm afraid that many follow Orwell in seeing grammaticality as not the only, indeed not the main, factor in assigning acceptability. I'd mark 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously' wrong in many contexts.